# Toggle though pictures using value of Count by button press

Tags: java, android

I have an app where I have 3 different picture galleries.  The pictures are displayed when a button is pressed, this displays a count on screen telling the user what number picture they are looking at.  The picture changes when the button is pressed and the count goes up.

The problem is I have 3 different galleries, I want the next gallery of pics to start straightaway after the first one.  So if I have 5 pics in gallery A, when the count reaches 5 and when the button is pressed again, I want the count to go back to 1 and onto the gallery B.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Here is my code so far:

```
public class picgalleries <onPause> extends Activity {

//Count Button
TextView txtCount;
ImageView image;
Button btnCount;
static int count=0;

txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);
txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.click);


count++;
count = 1; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1gallerya);
count = 2; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2gallerya);
count = 3; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3gallerya);
count = 4; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image4gallerya);
count = 5; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image5gallerya);

count = 1; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1galleryb);
count = 2; image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2galleryb);
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Comment: Are you attempting to write Java?  'if count = 1;' isn't valid Java syntax

Comment: Sorry I edited that later, i took the if's out

Comment: I think some more context is needed here in order for you to receive any help.  In particular I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between pictures and galleries.  Can a picture exist in more than one gallery?  Or is this app attempting to scroll through a set of exactly 15 pictures separated into 3 galleries?  It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: I have around 20 pics split into 3 different galleries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put them into a HashMap and key of this hashmap will be count and value will be resource id of corresponding picture so based on your count variable you can get relevant picture.